# What's the differences between ".*?" and "[^"]*" in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex. If I understand correctly, both

```
".*?"
```

and

```
"[^"]*"
```

should return any string within the two nearest quotes (including the quotes).

So for example, give below string

```
Here are "quote one" and "quote two"
```

The results returned by both regex should be

- `"quote one"`
- `"quote two"`

So in this case I understand both are the same. The only case they are different is the scenario that chris85 mentioned in the comments. Am I correct?

Comment: `.*?` wont match a new line without the `s` modifier. You can see how they work here, https://regex101.com/r/7Eq4Um/2, https://regex101.com/r/7Eq4Um/1

Comment: The difference it that they will match different strings. E.g. the first will match anything between double quotes, *including* strings containing double quotes. The second will match anything between double quotes, as long as it does not contain double quotes (or better: it will end the match as soon as the 2nd double quote is encountered).

Comment: @PeterB The first will not do what you think. The question mark makes it ungreedy.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you chris. I can see the differences now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By themselves, those two regexes are effectively the same.  The difference begins to matter when they are part of a larger expression.  For example, suppose you want to match only the second set of quotes, because it's at the end of the string.  If you used `".*?"$`, you would get:

```
"quote one" and "quote two"
```

...because `.` can match a quote, and the regex engine always takes the first match it finds.  However, `"[^"]*"$` will match only:

```
"quote two"
```

You may have heard that `.*?` always returns the shortest match.  As you've just seen, that's not true.  You also shouldn't expect it to be more efficient than `.*`; when there's no match possible, they're equally slow.

Reluctant quantifiers like `*?` are convenient, but you should always be prepared to use something tailored to your needs, like `[^"]*` or `(?:(?!don't match this).)*`, when the situation calls for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan!